# square connect api how to import fees to billing software

Tags: api, square-connect

Is there a way to retrieve the square processing fees when client transaction is processed online, to my billing software?

If yes, where and how can I retrieve them?

Comment: We are using v2, would it conflic in any way using v1 payment endpoint?

Comment: You committed your own question, so I wouldn't have seen this if I hadn't of stumbled upon it. No, there is no conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Use the [v1 Payments endpoints](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#navsection-payments) and look for `processing_fee_money`

Comment: do I need to use also RetrieveTransaction?

Comment: does this fall under Tenders?

Comment: Please take a look at the documentation: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#datatype-payment

Comment: $result = $transaction_api->charge($access_token, $location_id, $request_body);
$transaction_id = $result->getTransaction()->getId();
$url = 'https://example.com/modules/gateways/callback/squareup.php';
$hash = md5($_POST['invoice_id'].$transaction_id.$_POST['amount'].$_POST['secret_key']);
$invoice_id = $_POST['invoice_id'];
$fields = array(
'status' => urlencode("Success"),
'invoice_id' => urlencode($_POST['invoice_id']),
'trans_id' => urlencode($transaction_id),
'amount' => urlencode($_POST['amount']),
'currency' => urlencode($_POST['currency']),
'hash' => urlencode($hash)
 );

Comment: how can I use processing_fee in this.

Comment: That is a response from the v2Charge endpoint. You need to look up that transaction with the v1 retrieve payment endpoint https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#get-paymentid